# jQuery If then not working right

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```
    var searchString = '<strong>Applicable Discounts:</strong>';
    if ($(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')")) {
        $("#shipoptionstable td:contains('Free')").remove();
    } else {
        alert("do nothing!");
    };
```

For some reason the function is running and removing the shipoptionstable class table row even if the if condition is not being met? Any suggestions? Im stumped!

Comment: `if ($(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')").length)` because even an empty jQuery object is truly

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however I tried adding length but it is still removing the table when the value is not there

Comment: Try changing your `searchString` to `'Applicable Discounts'`. I am pretty sure you are not supposed to put elements into that selector with the corresponding greater than/less than symbols. Check this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zKD79/3/ ...notice that the `:contains` with the elements included in the `searchString` don't work. Remove those, and it will. Also, do what A. Wolff said (as you already have done).

Comment: Already tried that as well. I really want it to just detect if "applicable" is anywhere in the sentence... but my main concern is getting it to not throw a postive/truthy even when the searchstring is not there.

Comment: Some HTML would help to better see what you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Two points: First, the result of `$(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')")` will *always* be a jQuery object, regardless of the value of `searchString`. In fact, even if the DOM doesn't contain an element with class `cobhl` or it does, but that element has no decendant td element, it will still return a jQuery object.

Next, a non-null, non-undefined object is "truthy," meaning it doesn't literally have the Boolean value `true`, but it does evaluate as true for purposes of an if clause.

What you actually want to test is whether the returned jQuery object has a non-zero length. For example:

```
if ($(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')").length > 0) {
    ...
```

---

**Update**
Writing out the following values to the console will help you further debug the problem:

```
console.log("number of .cobhl elements: " + $(".cobhl").length);
console.log("number of .cobhl td elements: " + $(".cobhl td").length);
console.log("number of .cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "') elements: " + $(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')").length);
```

Examine the output from those statements. Are you getting any with the .cobhl selector? If yes, any td elements under that? If yes, is the searchString value what you expected?

Typically in this situation, I find that I have a typo farther up the selector chain. This technique of breaking down the selectors one at time helps me find it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried what you suggested, and it makes sense, however it is still the same as before, no popup if the Discounts field is not present, still removes the free option.

Comment: I do have multiple tables with the cobhl class. Should I make a single class for this ? Will that cause an issue?

Console returned:
number of .cobhl elements: 11
number of .cobhl td elements: 0
number of .cobhl td:contains('<strong>Applicable Discounts:</strong>') elements: 1

However, there are 0 instances of a TD with <strong>Applicable Discounts:</strong> showing up, which is what is needed to run the alert. If I enter a coupon code, I get 1 still.

Comment: When you write that there are 0 instances "showing up," do you mean that one more such elements exist in the document, but are not visible? If so, is it not visible because it's CSS display property is set to none or its visible property is set to hidden or is it because the element has simply scrolled out of view?

Comment: No I mean that it does not show up anywhere in the source nor is it hidden via css... it simply doesn't exist. I am going crazy trying to figure it out. So even though it doesn't exist, jQuery is still trying to say that there is 1 element ?

Comment: If $(".cobhl td:contains('" + searchString + "')").length yields 1, then there is one such element _somewhere_ in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out! Sometimes you just have to step away for a bit! Came back this morning and solved it within minutes!

```
<script>
var item = $('.cobhlappdisc');
for (var i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
   if ($(item[i]).text() == 'Applicable Discounts:') {
         alert("Did Stuff")
   }else{
       alert("Nope")  
      }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Might I suggest you start using `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging. Use a browser, such as Chrome, that has built in tools for debugging or even Firebug with Firefox.